# Problema al actualizar app Android Studio (nombre de paquete duplicado)

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una app publicada en el Play Store que deseo actualizar. Tengo la nueva versión con:

- Mismo nombre de app
- Mismo nombre de paquete
- Versión 2
- Firmada con la misma key

Cuando quiero instalarla en mi teléfono, donde tengo además instalada la versión anterior, primero me dice que se va a actualizar la aplicación y que no se perderán los datos almancenados (hasta aca bien). Pero luego la instalación falla y me dice:

> El paquete está en conflicto con otro paquete existente que tiene el
>   mismo nombre.

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas **actualizar** tu aplicación publicada en **Play Store** es necesario tener en cuenta 3 puntos.

> • El nombre del paquete debe ser el mismo.
>
> • El certificado con el que firmas tu aplicación que será una
>   actualización debe ser el mismo con el que firmaste la aplicación que
>   esta publicada.
>
> • El `versionCode` debe ser mayor al que tiene tu aplicación que se
>   encuentra publicada, considera también cambiar el `versionName` que
>   aunque no es requerimiento necesario es descriptivo que indica una
>   nueva versión.

Si obtienes el siguiente mensaje al tratar de instalar la aplicación.

> El paquete está en conflicto con otro paquete existente que tiene el
>   mismo nombre.

**Esto se refiere a que tienes instalada una aplicación pero esta fue firmada con un certificado diferente**, generalmente ocurre cuando subimos la aplicación desde Android Studio y este .apk se firma con el certificado de debug,

Simplemente sobreescribe la aplicación o elimina la que se encuentra instalada.